# Check for a certain condition before processing each view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm building a multi-tenant Django app, where I need to check for a certain condition before processing each view, similar to the `login_required` decorator which checks if user is authenticated or not.

And if the condition is not true, stop processing the view and send the user to the login page.

How can I implement this for each view in my app

My condition -

```
def index_view(request):
    domain1 = Domain.objects.get(tenant=request.user.client_set.first())
    domain2 = request.META["HTTP_HOST"].split(":")[0]

    # Condition
    if str(domain1) != domain2:
        return redirect("accounts:login")

    return render(request, "dashboard/index.html")
```

Comment: Create a decorator and add on each function

Comment: Do you use class-based or function-based views? Here's [an example in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test) for both cases. You can also create your own decorator or mixin to add to every view. Even better, if that condition should hold really for every request (maybe except for some known in advance, you can exclude some views from the middleware), [custom middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/middleware/) will be more DRY.

Comment: @AnkitTiwari Decorator doesn't have access to the `request` object, and I need that

Comment: @SUTerliakov  I think decorators are not the perfect solution because I need `request` object access in the decorator

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumar when you call your decorator on your function which accept request then it passed to your decorator too.

Comment: Hello @PraveenKumar did you get any solution for your question ?

Comment: Why do you even need to do this? Have you set [SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#session-cookie-domain)? Unless you set that logins are not cross domain making this not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a decorator which do this job for you

```
def check_domain(func):
    def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
        domain1 = Domain.objects.get(tenant=request.user.client_set.first())
        domain2 = request.META["HTTP_HOST"].split(":")[0]
        # Condition
        if str(domain1) != domain2:
           return redirect("accounts:login")
        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

---

```
@check_domain
def index_view(request):
    return render(request, "dashboard/index.html")
```

---

read more about decorators [here.](https://peps.python.org/pep-0318/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **@user_passes_test** decorator just like in the code below

create a method called **condition_to_fulfil(user)**

```
def condition_to_fulfil(user):
    # enter condition here
    if user_meets_condition:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Add the decorator above your view just like this

```
@login_required
@user_passes_test(condition_to_fulfil, login_url="/login/")
def index_view(request):
    domain1 = Domain.objects.get(tenant=request.user.client_set.first())
    domain2 = request.META["HTTP_HOST"].split(":")[0]
```

Comment: I need `request` object access inside **condition_to_fulfil** func, How can I do that?